# How can I get the underlying raw Variant value of a Delphi 6 indexed property that accesses that Variant?

Tags: delphi, properties, type-conversion, rtti, variant

I have a Delphi 6 class object that contains an array of 30 Variants, each of which is exposed via a different indexed property.  For example:

```
property responseCode: integer
        Index 7 read getIndexedProperty_integer write setIndexedProperty_integer;
```

I did this to make using the array of Variants easier (helps the IDE's auto-complete) and to provide type safety.  It works fine but now I have a wrinkle.  The array of Variants are initialized to NULL when the class that wraps it is constructed, so I can tell if a particular variant has ever been instantiated with a value.  A consequence of this is if only some of the Variants are instantiated (given valid values), any attempt to access a property that currently represents a NULL Variant will cause a Variant conversion error when Delphi tries to convert the variant to the type declared by the indexed property.

I would much rather not declare an "isValid" property for each indexed property.  I was wondering if there was a way to use the TypeInfo library to get the raw value of the underlying Variant without having to access the indexed property directly and thus triggering the conversion Exception.  Then I could write code like (using the example property above):

```
isValidProperty(responseCode);
```

and that function would return TRUE if the Variant underlying the responseCode property is not NULL and FALSE if it is.

I know I can walk the PPropList property list for the class and access the properties by name, but then I would have to use code like:

```
isValidProperty('responseCode');
```

and pass the property name in string form instead of passing in the property directly like the first isValidProperty() above.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I doubt which you can do that, because the rtti doesn't know nothing about the code to assign the variant value to the integer property located in the `getIndexedProperty_integer` method , so the underlying variant value can't be accessed in that way. my recomendation is which you modify the code of each getter method adding the `VarIsNull` function to check the variant values.

Comment: We're doing something similar, but the accessor is returning a default value in the case that the Variant is Null.

Comment: Why does using variants "provide type safety"?  It gives the opposite in a sense: you have the problem here of not knowing the underlying type and only being able to find out at runtime.  Wouldn't a better solution be to have an array of integers, or if each of the 30 has a different type, explicitly have different properties?

Comment: @DavidM.  Variants don't provide type safety, that's what the type-safe (explicitly declared) indexed properties that access the Variants do.  Variants provide flexibility in other capacities that are needed by my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want "to get the raw value of the underlying Variant without having to access the indexed property directly and thus triggering the conversion Exception".  So long as you can access the underlying Variant itself, yes, you can.  You will need to change the container class itself most likely.

From [the Delphi XE2 help page on variant types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types):

> The standard function `VarType` returns a variant's type code. The
>   `varTypeMask` constant is a bit mask used to extract the code from
>   `VarType`'s return value, so that, for example,

```
VarType(V) and varTypeMask = varDouble
```

> returns `True` if `V` contains a `Double` or an
>   `array of Double`. (The mask simply hides the first bit, which indicates
>   whether the variant holds an array.) The `TVarData` record type defined
>   in the `System` unit can be used to typecast variants and gain access to
>   their internal representation.

You should be able to use a combination of the methods and records mentioned here to find out anything you want about the internal data inside the variant, including if it's a NULL variant, as well as getting direct access to it.

(This system seems slightly dodgy design to me: it doesn't seem a very type safe implementation... see my comment above.  I think a design based on the actual types of the values you are expecting might be safer.  But, this will let you achieve your goal.)